# Illustration for number system using tikz tree

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-trees

I want to create an illustration for number systems like this one

[image]

Here is my MWE.

```
\documentclass[landscape]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

\usepackage[margin=1in]{geometry}
\usepackage{tikz-qtree}
\usetikzlibrary{shadows,trees}
\begin{document}
\tikzset{font=\small,
edge from parent fork down,
level distance=1.75cm,
every node/.style=
    {top color=white,
    bottom color=blue!25,
    rectangle,rounded corners,
    minimum height=8mm,
    draw=blue!75,
    very thick,
    drop shadow,
    align=center,
    text depth = 0pt
    },
edge from parent/.style=
    {draw=blue!50,
    thick
    }}

\centering
\begin{tikzpicture}
\Tree [.{Real Numbers}
        [.{Rational\\ $a$}
          [.{Integers}
              [.{Negative Integers} ]
              [.{Whole Numbers} 
                [.Zero ]
                [.{Natural}
                  [.Even
                  [.Odd ]
                ]
            ] ]]
          [.Fraction
            ] 
            ]
        [.{Irrational\\ $a$} 
]
]
]
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

After "natural" I lost track.

**Edited**: Using the following code, the leaves overlap

```
\documentclass[a4paper,10pt]{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{fullpage}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning,shadows,arrows,trees,shapes,fit}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
[font=\small, edge from parent fork down,
every node/.style={top color=white, bottom color=blue!25,
rectangle,rounded corners, minimum size=6mm, draw=blue!75,
very thick, drop shadow, align=center},
edge from parent/.style={draw=blue!50,thick},
level 1/.style={sibling distance=6cm},
level 2/.style={sibling distance=2.5cm},
level 3/.style={sibling distance=2.5cm},
level distance=2cm,
]
\node {Real} % root
    child { node {Rational}
        child { node {Int}
        child { node {negative}}
        child { node {whole}
        child { node {zero}}
        child { node {natural} 
        child { node {even}
        child { node {prime}}
        child { node {composit}}
        }
        child { node {odd}
         child { node {1}}
         child { node {prime}}
         child { node {composit}}
        }}
        }}
        child { node {frac}}
        } 
    child { node {irrational}}
;
\end{tikzpicture} 
\end{document}
```

Comment: While this is beside the point of your question, several of the terms on the tree are not standard terminology, or would at least be ambiguous to mathematicians. “Fractions” are the same as “rational numbers,” and “whole numbers” can mean either the integers, the natural numbers starting from 0, or the natural numbers starting from 1. So I wouldn’t give this tree to students.

Comment: @Davislor I feel that way too. But I just want to draw the tree.

Comment: Could you be a little more specific about the TeX syntax you want help with? You seem to understand how to nest tree nodes and add math-mode expressions, just fine.

Comment: @Davislor Honestly, I don't know what to do after the ``natural numbers'' on the diagram.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I understand your question correctly, consistent indentation should make the logical relationship of the nested partitions straightforward.

```
\documentclass[landscape]{article}
\usepackage{libertinus}

\usepackage[margin=1in]{geometry}
\usepackage{tikz-qtree}
\usetikzlibrary{shadows,trees}
\begin{document}
\tikzset{font=\small,
edge from parent fork down,
level distance=1.75cm,
every node/.style=
    {top color=white,
    bottom color=blue!25,
    rectangle,rounded corners,
    minimum height=8mm,
    draw=blue!75,
    very thick,
    drop shadow,
    align=center,
    text depth = 0pt
    },
edge from parent/.style=
    {draw=blue!50,
    thick
    }}

\centering
\begin{tikzpicture}
\Tree [.{Real Numbers}
        [.{Rational Numbers \\ \( \left\{ -5, \frac{-7}{3}, 0, \frac{5}{6} \right\} \)}
          [.{Integers \\ \( \{ -50, -1, 0, 1, 2, 17 \} \)}
            [.{Negative Integers \\ \( \{ -1,-2,-96 \} \)}
            ]
            [.{Natural Numbers\footnotemark[1] \\ \( \{ 0, 1, 2, 27 \} \)}
              [.{Even Numbers}
                [.{\(0\)}
                ]
                [.{\(2\)}
                ]
                [.{Even Composites}
                ]
              ]
              [.{Odd Numbers}
                [.{\(1\)}
                ]
                [.{Odd Primes \\ \( \{ 3, 5, 7, 11 \} \)}
                ]
                [.{Odd Composites \\ \( \{ 9, 15, 25, 27 \} \)}
                ]
              ]
            ]
          ]
          [.{Non-Integers \\ \( \left\{ \frac{1}{2}, \frac{5}{3}, \frac{7}{5} \right\} \)}
          ]
        ]
        [ .{Irrational Numbers \\ \( \left\{ \sqrt{2}, \sqrt{3}, \pi, \right\} \)}
        ]
      ]
\end{tikzpicture}

\footnotetext[1]{Not all mathematicians consider \(0\) a natural number.}
\end{document}
```

[image: Tree diagram]

I could not help myself from pedantically correcting some nodes of the tree. (Even so, I didn’t write “Positive” before “Even” and “Odd”, because it spoils the layout.)